# I need to use MS Access to read a .txt file, modify the records and add a header record

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a .txt file with records that are tab delimited between attributes.
Basically looks like this:

```
1234567898765432123456  Charleston  2021-03-17 07:25:31
23456789876543212345  Baltimore  2021-03-17 07:26:32
```

I need to:

1. add a header record (include count of detail records if this is possible?)
2. add an identifying character "DR" at the beginning of the record
3. make the records fixed length attributes and not tab delimited
4. reformat the date / time to drop dashes and colons

Update to look like this:

```
HeaderRecordNbr001 DetailRecordCnt00002
DR1234567898765432123456 Charleston     DT20210317072531
DR23456789876543212345   Baltimore      DT20210317072632
```

I created two processes.  The first to import the data into Access  with some transformation:

```
Dim fileNum As Integer
Dim dataLine As String
Dim column1 As String
Dim column2 As String
Dim column3 As String
Dim column4 As String
Dim column5 As String
Dim column6 As String
Dim column7 As String
Dim column8 As String
Dim column9 As String
Dim column10 As String


fileNum = FreeFile()
ReportPath = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\FilePickup\"
FileName = ReportPath & "testfile " & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd ") & "001" & ".txt"
DBEngine(0)(0).Execute "DELETE FROM MyTable"
Open FileName For Input As #fileNum

While Not EOF(fileNum)
    Line Input #fileNum, dataLine
    If Len(dataLine) > 1 Then
        column1 = "DR"
        column2 = Mid(dataLine, 1, 22)
        column3 = Mid(dataLine, 24, 10)
        column4 = "DT"
        column5 = Mid(dataLine, 36, 4)
        column6 = Mid(dataLine, 41, 2)
        column7 = Mid(dataLine, 44, 2)
        column8 = Mid(dataLine, 47, 2)
        column9 = Mid(dataLine, 50, 2)
        column10 = Mid(dataLine, 53, 2)
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO MyTable(column1, column2, column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7, Column8, Column9, Column10) VALUES('" & column1 & "', '" & column2 & "', '" & column3 & "', '" & column4 & "', '" & column5 & "', '" & column6 & "', '" & column7 & "', '" & column8 & "', '" & column9 & "', '" & column10 & "')"
    End If
Wend

Close #fileNum
```

The second process to export back out to a .txt file, adding a header record.  But I can't get the header record to use a date variable, or get the actual detail record count.  any help would be appreciated?

```
Const VB_FORREADING = 1
Const VB_FORWRITING = 2
Const cstrFile As String = "C:\Users\Documents\Access\Reports\UpdatedFileOutput.txt"
Const cstrHeaderRow As String = "HeaderRecord202103181606   0000000010301            "
Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim strContents As String

' do TransferText without the field names '
' (HasFieldNames default = False) '
DoCmd.TransferText acExportFixed, "Export_Specification", _
    "Record_Stg", cstrFile

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' read file content into strContents string variable '
Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(cstrFile, VB_FORREADING)
strContents = oFile.ReadAll
oFile.Close
' re-write file using cstrHeaderRow plus strContents '
Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(cstrFile, VB_FORWRITING)
oFile.Write cstrHeaderRow & vbCrLf & strContents
oFile.Close

Set oFile = Nothing
Set oFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: Do you have any code so far?

Comment: Use the _FileSystemObject_. It can do all of this easily.

Comment: I'm not experienced with VBA.  I currently only use it to run queries against external dbs, drop results in Excel, format, then email it out.  I wasn't sure if I should import the .txt file into Access first, then export it back out as the easiest way to do this?  I'm not familiar with FileSystemObject but I'll check it out.

Comment: I've been able to Google for code others have shared that get's me close.  I've tweaked and accomplished most of what I need.  I've updated the original question with the code and outstanding issues

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a table for this, it's easier and faster with strings only.

You are missing a few crucial ingredients, specifically the Split() and Format() functions.
I'll outline how I would do it (air code):

```
strIn = inFile.ReadAll
varFile = Split(strIn, vbCrLf)
nRows = UBound(varFile)+1

strOut = "Header ... Rows: " & nRows & "  Date: " & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhnnss")

For y = LBound(varFile) To UBound(varFile)
    strRow = varFile(y)
    varRow = Split(strRow, vbTab)

    col1 = Space$(30)
    LSet col1, varRow(0)
    ' LSet is kinda obscure. Alternative:
    col1 = Left$(varRow(0) & Space$(30), 30)

    ' Same for col2

    ' col3 has valid datetime format: "2021-03-17 07:25:31"
    myDate = CDate(varRow(2))
    col3 = "DT" & Format(myDate, "yyyymmddhhnnss")

    strOut = strOut & vbCrlf & col1 & col2 & col3
Next y

' Write strOut to outfile, done.

'-----------------

' Simple, plain VBA functions to read/write text files

Public Function TextFileRead(sFile As String) As String

    Open sFile For Input As #1
    TextFileRead = Input$(LOF(1), #1)
    Close #1
    
End Function

Public Sub TextFileWrite(sFile As String, sData As String)

    Open sFile For Output As #1
    Print #1, sData
    Close #1
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Andre - I appreciate the suggestion, sounds great.  Unfortunately I'm not experienced enough to figure out my objects, variable, etc and get that code to compile?

Comment: All str* are string variables, var* are Variant. There are no objects, only arrays returned by Split() - see online docs. File reading/writing you already have covered, you can also use simple VBA functions e.g. as added to the answer. @BrucePavkov